# Exercising visual spatial intelligence using interactive storytelling

Tags: development, teaching, middle-childhood, learning, imaginative-play

What is the best way to exercise visual spatial intelligence for my 8 year old in regards to interactive story telling?

I currently have her describe the surrounding environment she envisions in as much detail as possible. Then I guide her through adding more details to the environment she envisions to create as detailed of a landscape as she can hold in her mind. Then as we think up the story we place each character/object within the landscape she is holding in memory, specifying as many details as possible (characters, patterns, colors, quantity, geospatial placement relative to existing story objects, etc).

Which would be a better brain exercise?

1. Have them rely on their imagination entirely and visualize every aspect by themselves as they think of each detail?
2. Present them with an initial image of a landscape as a foundation for the story. Then have them place each detail of the story on the landscape presented?

Why?

Comment: Visual spatial intelligence won't be helped by either. Imagination, yes. Spatial relationships have to do with objects in space (near/far/left/right/up/down, all *together*.) Speaking to a child doesn't really help with this. What is your child's age? I did do spatial intelligence exercises with my kids as part of their schooling. If you clarify what you're looking for, and the  age of the child involved, you'll get a more helpful answer. Thanks.

Comment: From an earlier question it looks like the child is 9 years old. If that's accurate, OP please edit that in. Thanks!

Comment: I incorporate spacial relations by first having her describe the surrounding environment she envisions in as much detail as possible. Then guide her through adding more details to the environment to envision as detailed of a landscape as she can hold in your mind. Then as we think up the story we place each character/object within the landscape she is holding in memory, specifying the exact position, quanity, and relative position to everything else already placed in the story.

Comment: I'm skeptical that this will do anything for visual spatial skills, but good luck.

Comment: I might suggest you add a definition for how you define visual spatial intelligence - I feel like there is a disconnect here perhaps.

Comment: The ability to imagine or visualize with the minds eye the positions of objects, their shapes, their spatial relations to one another and the movement they make to form new spatial relations.

Comment: @McWayWeb - You can't do it with thoughts (stories) alone. You need a reality, a drawing or a concrete object against which you can compare to see how accurate (and difficult) it really is. You can do it with paper and pencil, though, especially if they know *angles*. You'll see that the initial attempts to draw a 3-D object with directions alone (no help) are way off/very frustrating. With little ones, you can start with colored blocks, or toys. But not words alone.